# How Can I completely prevent internet acess from my laptop

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet-connection, wifi-driver

Is there a way to  completely prevent internet access from my laptop

I mean even if someone tried to connect the internet he will not be able unless using external data from a flash memory or a password

I am using windows 8 so I think even if I uninstalled the driver(of network and wireless cards) the windows will automatically detect it

I can think of removing the wired and wireless cards : but is this easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the wireless card is easy - typically this is some flavour of mini pci(e) or NGFF - at worst, you'd need to open up your laptop. On many models this would take you a few minutes, though some laptops may need you to dismantle the whole base or more.

Removing wired internet is hard. Typically its a chip *on* the motherboard, and I doubt you want to simply desolder it.

If you *must* disable a wired ethernet port, there's devices marketed as 
"[RJ45 port blockers](https://www.google.com.sg/?client=firefox-b-ab#q=rj45%20port%20blocker&gfe_rd=cr)" that fit over an ethernet port. They arn't *impossible* to remove (even without the special tool they come with) but would make it somewhat less trivial.

[image]

If this is for self control issues, feel free to loose the tool ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `disable` any network adapters in the Device Manager.  Only people with administrator access would be able to enable it again.

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine if you uninstalled any browsers and email clients, you would not be able to connect.  Just keep any installer files you might need in the future.

Comment: you would "imagine" incorrectly.

Comment: you can't remove Edge or Internet explorer

Comment: Then go here to ask your questions.  http://www.tenforums.com/

Comment: And removing the programs you know could use the Internet doesn't account for **any** other program that may use it.  This is not a solution to the question.